# How are movies distributed internationally?

Tags: distribution

How is a movie, for example a Hollywood movie that is produced in USA make it across the globe?

In what form of storage device and who has the responsibility of physically transferring the movie from one country to another? Or is it done through the Internet?

Comment: Related, partial dupe: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53468/how-are-digital-movies-sent-to-a-movie-theater If you're only interested in digital, that question answers you.

Comment: Take a look at this [**Wikipedia article**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_distributor). See sections **Theatrical distribution** and **International distribution**.

Comment: Are you asking about physical distribution or things like DVD region lock ins so some movies cannot play in certain countries or regions?

Answer (score 1):

Digital movies are currently transported to the cinemas on a Hard Drive Disks, a movie takes somewhere around 500 GB of storage space. This disks are locked with special securities and cannot be played outside of given time windows.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: Well, my source is a technical director of a big cinema in my town, who gave me a tour and showed how the digital cinema works, with all the projectors, sound systems, and so on, but I found this online with some knowledge on this topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Cinema_Package